# How to update struct data for array

Tags: go

I am trying to update "age" of data struct using SetAge() function after the array creation in the user struct. Here is the code snippet:

```
//data struct to set the user details
type data struct {
  Name        string `json:"name"`
  College     string `json:"college"`
  Age         int64  `json:"age"`
}

// user struct to store the user details in JSON Array        
type user struct {
    DataValue     []*data `json:"data"`
}

func (u *user) Details(name, college string) *user {
  d:=&data{Name:name, College:college}
  u.DataValue=append(u.DataValue, d)
  return u
}

func (u *user) SetAge(age int64) *user { //age is optional
  // what code should be here such that age is added to resp detail
}

Output:
"data":[{
  "name":"test",
  "college":"test",
  "age":10
},{
  "name":"test",
  "college":"test" 
  // in this object "Age" hasn't been set
}]
```

Comment: A note on terminology: There aren't any arrays in your code. You're using a slice.

Comment: What help do you want? You seem to know how to update struct fields because you do it in `Details`. So what specifically do you want help on? Have you done the go tour to introduce yourself to the fundamentals of the language? https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: What should SetAge actually do?

Shall it set the age field in "all" data elements with the given value?

Comment: You should look at your problem from another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `Age` field of **all** the `data` objects, *You're almost done*.

You just need to iterate over the `u.DataValue` slice, and update the age field as follows:

```
func (u *user) SetAge(age int64) *user {
    for index := range u.DataValue {
        u.DataValue[index].Age = age
    }
    return u
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update the **Age** field of all the `data` objects. In my application it would be like
`resp:=u.Details("name","college").SetAge(10).Details("name2","college2")`

Answer (score -2):

As per the requirement in my application, it would be like this:

```
func (u *user) SetAge(age int64) *user {
    u.DataValue[len(u.DataValue) - 1].Age = age
    return u
}
```